# ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 8: Table 'session' already exists;

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, roundcube

I've been trying to install roundcube on ubuntu server. But when i try to run the command below, i am always receveing the error message.
sudo mysql -u username -passwd roundcube < /var/www/roundcube/SQL/mysql.initial.sql

Please help me out in this!

Comment: The session table already exists. You probably tried to run the command before, and it either worked or failed. Delete all of the tables (or at least the session table) or create a new database and try again.

Comment: i've tried again with creating new db. But let me try one more time.

Comment: After i've tried dropping the session db, it's still showing the error as :ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 20: Table 'users' already exists

Comment: Well, that's a whole different table, isn't it. Same issue, same fix, though.

Comment: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails. I have this error now when i try to drop the table.

Comment: You might be better off creating a whole new database and inserting into that

Comment: Thanks, it was resolved as of now. But i am not load the roundcube installer on the browser. When i put the url like http://domain_name/installer/ . Nothing shows it's blank. So i am not sure what to do more here.